# In knitr, figure heights do not obey my opts_chunk$set commands when sizes are changed on the fly

Tags: html, r, knitr

I am trying to create HTML files using R package knitr but I am finding the entire experience quite hard, possibly because the documentation is sparse when not using LaTeX (and when one does not know Sweave). The specific problem is this:

I wish to produce two similar charts in the HTML file, but each must have a different height. So here is my RHTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>



<!--begin.rcode
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, dpi=96, fig.width=9, fig.height=8, dev="png")
  print("Width 9, height 8")
  plot(rnorm(100), col="orange")
end.rcode-->

<hr> 

<!--begin.rcode
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, dpi=96, fig.width=9, fig.height=12, dev="png")
  print("Width 9, height 12")
  plot(rnorm(100), col="purple")
end.rcode-->

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the two (simple) plots must have the same width (9) but different heights (8 then 12). This is trivially easy in R, but knitr seems to want to keep the aspect ratio the same. Here are the two plot outputs:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the lower one does not have the aspect ratio that I want, and they are different widths.

Also, I am getting all this chunk output at the top of my html file that I thought I was suppressing with echo=FALSE....

[image]

How might I fix all of this? Does opts_chunk$set set some kind of global option only once? What if I want to reset options each time I output a new graph? And how do I suppress *all* knitr package output?

Comment: Just a suggestion on troubleshooting these things generally: make sure `cache = FALSE` and throw away the figures and cache subfolders which ensures they all get updated. Be sure that as many options are set in the `setup` chunk as possible.  Then, only modify chunk options in the chunk where they change.  Also, I always put `rm(list = ls())` in my set up chunk to make certain parameters written into the global environment don't hang around.  Also, the typesetting produces intermediate files - throw those away too to force fresh copies.  Finally, you might look at function `spin` in `knitr`.

Comment: Okay just tried all that. rm(list = ls()); erased all the pngs in the figure directory, reloaded the browser, cleared its cache; no joy. Still the same. As I am not actually typesetting (it's just HTML), other than the "figure" directory, what else needs to be cleared that you know of?
By the way, what is the "setup chunk"?

Comment: It's nothing formal, but many people use the first code chunk to set up both `knitr` and `R` options & settings. It would have `opts_chunk` and `library("whatever")` for example.  Also, if you are relying on global variables you missing the virtues of reproducible research.  If at all possible make your script generate or at least get these values from a `csv` or `RData` or something similar.

Comment: no the global variables are updated constantly and yes, I should probably move them to another file. Issue is, they're each about 3 gb (massive, and highly complex, yield curve analysis lists using termstrc). Anyway the above super simple still doesn't work!

Comment: I don't have experience with the exact approach you are using - are you hand writing that html code and then running `knitr` on it?  If so, look at `spin`.  I think it's odd that you call `opts_chunk` every time but maybe that is how this flavor of knitting works.  I assume you've been all over http://yihui.name/knitr/options and some of the demo examples at the same site?

Comment: yep hand coded HTML. But the above is an extremely simple example to isolate the problem. The issue is cropping up in my much more complex production code (2500 lines of R code). Just ran "spin" and it simply put ''' at the top ;). I have dozens of complex chart output, most of which requires strict aspect ratio formatting, and if I can't get the above simple example working, then I'm going to abandon the knitr approach altogether and simply output PNG files and call them natively in HTML. Will lose flexibility though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34329/discussion-between-thomas-browne-and-bryan-hanson)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I guess I need to explain this behavior in the documentation. All my examples do `opts_chunk$set()` in the very first chunk, though, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-manual.Rnw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with repeatedly setting `opts_chunk` though I don't  know why it shouldn't work the way you want.  Regardless, here is a working example.  I won't post the result to save space, but it looks like you want - sizes are respected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--begin.rcode Setup, echo = FALSE
  opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, dpi=96, fig.width=9, fig.height=8, dev="png")
end.rcode-->

<!--begin.rcode Fig1
  print("Width 9, height 8")
  plot(rnorm(100), col="orange")
end.rcode-->

<hr> 

<!--begin.rcode Fig2, fig.width=9, fig.height=12
  print("Width 9, height 12")
  plot(rnorm(100), col="purple")
end.rcode-->

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a dream, except I had to put a comma in after the Setup so on my system at least the first chunk line had to read: <!--begin.rcode Setup, echo=FALSE

Comment: Excellent.  I learned something too - never tried `knitr` with an `Rhtml` file.

Comment: the key is, options set in `opts_chunk` will be applied to all the _following_ chunks but not the current chunk